# Alternatives to Singletons for caching lists of data?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, singleton

In my project, I have an abstract `Cache` class that allows me to populate a series of lists that globally persist throughout my application. These cache objects are thread-safe and can be manipulated as necessary, and allow for me to cut-down on the massive overhead of querying external third-party APIs directly. I've seen some serious hate for singletons, so I'm a bit curious what other options I have when this is my current use case.

I've seen dependency injection mentioned quite a bit, but I don't know if it's quite adequate or useful in this scenario.

Here is an example of my `Cache` abstract class:

```
public abstract class Cache<TU, T>
    where TU : Cache<TU, T>, new()
    where T : class
{
    private static readonly TU Instance = new TU();
    private static volatile State _currentState = State.Empty;
    private static volatile object _stateLock = new object();
    private static volatile object _dataLock = new object();
    private static DateTime _refreshedOn = DateTime.MinValue;
    private static T InMemoryData { get; set; }

    public static T Data
    {
        get
        {
            switch (_currentState)
            {
                case State.OnLine:
                    var timeSpentInCache = (DateTime.UtcNow - _refreshedOn);
                    if (timeSpentInCache > Instance.GetLifetime())
                    {
                        lock (_stateLock)
                        {
                            if (_currentState == State.OnLine) _currentState = State.Expired;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case State.Empty:
                    lock (_dataLock)
                    {
                        lock (_stateLock)
                        {
                            if (_currentState == State.Empty)
                            {
                                InMemoryData = Instance.GetData();
                                _refreshedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                _currentState = State.OnLine;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case State.Expired:
                    lock (_stateLock)
                    {
                        if (_currentState == State.Expired)
                        {
                            _currentState = State.Refreshing;
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(Refresh);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            lock (_dataLock)
            {
                if (InMemoryData != null) return InMemoryData;
            }

            return Data;
        }
    }

    public static T PopulateData()
    {
        return Data;
    }

    protected abstract T GetData();

    protected virtual TimeSpan GetLifetime()
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    }

    private static void Refresh()
    {
        if (_currentState != State.Refreshing) return;
        var dt = Instance.GetData();
        lock (_stateLock)
        {
            lock (_dataLock)
            {
                _refreshedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                _currentState = State.OnLine;
                InMemoryData = dt;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Invalidate()
    {
        lock (_stateLock)
        {
            _refreshedOn = DateTime.MinValue;
            _currentState = State.Expired;
        }
    }

    private enum State
    {
        Empty,
        OnLine,
        Expired,
        Refreshing
    }
}
```

And an example of its implementation.

```
public class SalesForceCache
{
    public class Users : Cache<Users, List<Contact>>
    {
        protected override List<Contact> GetData()
        {
            var sf = new SalesForce();
            var users = sf.GetAllUsers();

            sf.Dispose();

            return users;
        }

        protected override TimeSpan GetLifetime()
        {
            try
            {
                return TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            }
            catch (StackOverflowException)
            {
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Accounts : Cache<Accounts, List<Account>>
    {
        protected override List<Account> GetData()
        {
            var sf = new SalesForce();
            var accounts = sf.GetAllAccounts();

            sf.Dispose();

            return accounts;
        }

        protected override TimeSpan GetLifetime()
        {
            try
            {
                return TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            }
            catch (StackOverflowException)
            {
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "cache object**s**", plural. Are you sure Cache is a singleton and not just a global variable?

Comment: The cache objects are a series of classes that implement my abstract `Cache` class. I can post an example of the classes in the OP if that's more helpful.

Comment: @Ixrec I updated the OP with an example.

Comment: In one place you have `lock (_dataLock) { lock (_stateLock)` and in another place you have `lock (_stateLock) { lock (_dataLock)`.  So, you are liable to experience a deadlock.

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you think that you need static variables and a singleton pattern at all? What would fail if you just wrote a normal abstract base class?

Comment: I'm merely wanting large-expensive datasets to persist across a variety of different classes and methods. And these datasets should be readily available for every web-api call that comes into our service.

Comment: Ok. Again, why do you think you need a Singleton for that? Why can't you do it with a normal class?

Comment: Because I only want the class to be instantiated one time and allow it to be used among all the required classes without it having to be passed either as: a) a parameter or b) globally static.

Comment: A singleton *is* a global. Why don't you want to pass the instance around as a parameter? Is it really the case that *every* class in your program uses this object, or only just a few?

Comment: They're actually used pretty profusely. Also, part of it comes from me not knowing exactly how the persistence is going to work in the webapp. I'm just trying to ensure that the data persists constantly.

Comment: I think dependency injection IS adequate in this scenario. A container could manage your cache and it would be fairly easy to control the scope. You could have a cache per application, per session, per request, etc. with very little boilerplate code.

Comment: I guess it comes with me being a very visual person. I've drawn out a few use cases and scenarios to get an idea of what "should" happen, it just comes down to the implementation now. In theory, I could implement the entire `SyncTool.Core` as a singleton that gets instantiated by `SyncTool.Web` when it starts up, and the `SyncTool.Core` would manage everything as standard classes as it will persist throughout the application's lifetime.

Comment: ^^^^ yes, that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the "serious hate" for singletons trouble you. Anyone who says "always" or "never" is ignorant. Or deranged. Or secretly crying for help.

Conceptually, a cache is a singleton. There's no getting around it. It's sitting in memory somewhere, waiting. Many readers and writers are accessing that one chunk of memory (barring a disk-backed cache). I imagine the dependency injection solutions are talking about injecting an abstraction over the cache. There may be many of them, but if you dig deep enough (not even that deep, really), there should only ever be one cache.

My team's rule of thumb is that singletons *may* be okay for a single source of truth. That sounds like what you're dealing with.

One observation about your current solution: In my ideal world, as a casual consumer I never want to see the word "Cache" in the code I'm using. If I want a collection of Users, I'd rather say

```
var store = new UserStore();
return store.GetUsers()
```

than

```
return SalesForceCache.Users.Data;
```

The word "Cache" is mental overhead. When I use it, I'm suddenly thinking about the "how" the data is stored versus "what" I want. Sure, there may be a cache under the hood of my `UserStore`, but it's hidden from me. And that's a good thing. Some other plumbing should decide if something is cached and for how long.

Also, there are a few possible future frustrations:

1. The storage mechanism is rigid. You can only ever store a collection. That may not be what I want. For instance, maybe I want to store active Users individually, with a sliding expiration, by email address. (Super useful when you have many users but only a handful of them are online at one time.)
2. Expirations are absolute. It can be useful to define a sliding expiration. (especially under memory constraint when you only want the most active data in memory)
3. There are no cache dependencies. Cache dependencies allow you to automatically expire cached data when specific conditions are met.

Take a look at [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) for an easy-to-use local memory cache. It's feature rich and uses the idioms common in key/value caches. I absolutely don't want to discourage you from continuing with your approach! Keep at it! The MemoryCache might serve as an interesting reference.

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer, because it contains some useful advice, but I can't, because it encourages singletons.  C-:=  (I have not downvoted either, because the fact that we disagree on something does not automatically mean that your answer is not useful.)

Comment: @MikeNakis My main objective was to convince everyone a cache can be nothing but a singleton. I guess I wasn't successful. To elaborate... C# requires a reference. Without it, the thing being referenced is GC'd. You can copy that reference as much as you'd like, but you can't let the reference count drop to zero. So in long-running applications, you have to keep at least one reference alive at all times. The only way I can think to guarantee that reference is to store it statically. Conceptually, that makes it a singleton.

Comment: ... I suppose you could serialize and persist between use, but that sort of defeats the efficiencies. I'm not advocating for singletons everywhere, but in this case I don't see how you get around it. A chunk of memory set aside so it can be used at different times between different users/requests/etc has to be a singleton. Am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: The reason why singletons are considered bad is because their use implies an assumption about the extent and lifetime of the system. Case in point: say, you have a client-server application, and the client has a singleton cache of type `Map<Key,Foo>` and the server has its own singleton cache of `Map<Key,Foo>`.  One day you decide that to ease development you are going to build a standalone version of your app, which combines both server and client. Suddenly now the server's cache is mixed with the client's cache. You have a ***Catastrophe***.

Comment: But I am sure that this discussion has been had countless times before, in other answers on Programmers SE and on Stackoverflow, so let's not repeat it all over here.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm aware of why singletons are bad and don't disagree. I still don't see how a chunk of memory that persists between users and requests can anything _but_ a singleton. What else would it be? (Don't worry. I hate singletons too.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create one cache instance per third-party API instance.  If your third-party APIs do not come in instances, then encapsulate them into some instantiatable C# wrapper.
2. You can make your caches members of your one great big root `Application` object. If you do not have one, come up with one.  This is the only thing which may legitimately be a singleton.  (But even then, it should only be a singleton in the sense that it will be `new`ed once, not in the sense of consisting of static methods.)

Comment: On #1, I instantiate my third party APIs each time an operation is occurring as they have timeouts, and continued operations within them can causes issues. On point #2, my solution consists of 4 key projects. `SyncTool.Web` (my controllers, web interfaces, etc). `SyncTool.Core` (my actual service. It transforms data from each service into BDOs). 2 Third Party API wrappers (these handle the reading/writing of data to the services).

Comment: Your "Application" in this case is most probably that which you call "my actual service".

Comment: I was originally intending on just instantiating the `Synctool.Core` either within each controller method or building it out as a singleton to be instantiated on its first use. Much like how my Cache objects operate in the OP.

Comment: Okay, I see. But don't you have some class somewhere which implements the main entry point of the application and instantiates and connects everything?

Comment: In my current implementation it's simply the `global.asax`, I'm doing a full rewrite of the application. So I'm looking into building my `SyncTool.Core` as a singleton and simply initializing it on the `global.asax` versus how I do everything now. In theory, I could simply define these as standard classes and initialize them in my `SyncTool.Core.Main` constructor though.

Answer (score 1):

> ... without it having to be passed either as: a) a parameter or b) globally static.

Pick one. There is no third option.

You either pass the "data querying" abstraction as parameter, with cache serving as a decorator, or you access the cache through globally static property. I would recommend the first, because then it makes the dependency explicit and allows you to transparently separate the caching and data acquisition.

My take why Singletons are bad, is that they break SRP. They have two responsibilities : whatever the singleton is supposed to do and handing it's lifetime. Those two are exclusive and should be separate. Reason why people recommend IoC is to move the lifetime handling outside the singleton and into to IoC container.